# What are persisted objects called in an MVC application?

Tags: model-view-controller, naming

If you persist data in a relational database and use the MVC or HMVC architectures, would a table correspond to a model? If not, what would you call that type of object? I've been hearing debates where some people call them domain objects and others don't differentiate the two.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been hereing debates where some people call them domain objects and others don't defferenciate the two

--> That's because this doesn't matter at all. **Domain** eg. from mathematics can be seen as the model because it defines the data type, range, complexity, ... = the set of possible values for your logic or function. This is mostly identical to a model. In addition to that this does not change anything to call them domain objects or model entities or whatever. The **Model** (in MVC world) is a concept. The way you define/implement your model is completely up to you as soon as you maintain the separation with the other layers and fits the concept.